# Unable to understand scm sync pop up message on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using Multi-branch pipeline Jenkins jobs with SCM sync 
Configuration plugin installed. Since few days a warning is being popping up at the end of Jenkins console. Can anyone explain what it is trying to inform us.

Error: **Delete jobs/wbe-middle-layer-inbound/branches/feature-LMS-4271-Release2.83lj1k**

Here we in git we don't have branch **feature-LMS-4271-Release2.83lj1k** under **wbe-middle-layer-inbound** repo but having **feature-LMS-4271-Release2**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Periodically the multi-branch pipeline job just scan your repo to determine if any of it's branches meet the criteria for a pipeline to be created for them.  It also tells you the pipelines it deletes because the branch that it was matched to is no longer there.  Could that be what you're seeing?

Comment: Correct . How can I avoid displaying this message. 
Note: I don't want to disable "Display SCM Sync Status" and also please note that I have enabled "prune stale remote-tracking branches" in Jenkins job already. -Thanks